# Xcode 11 Segues

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, xcode11

Whenever I am using segues in the Xcode 11 beta (here just changing between two VCs using a swipe gesture), the second VC pops up as a card:

[image]

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Id take a look at this article. It explains well why its happening and gives an example of how to revert it back to the standard style.

[View Controller Presentation Changes](https://medium.com/@hacknicity/view-controller-presentation-changes-in-ios-13-ac8c901ebc4e)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Full screen modal presentation it is, figured it!

Comment: yeah no problem, glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is doing the segue programmatically, the code needs to be something similar to this:

```
@objc func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let vc = ViewControllerB() //Destination controller

    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen  // This line is needed now
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal

    self.present( vc, animated: true, completion: nil )
}
```